# Altering an existing column to 'Primary Key' and 'NOT NULL' without dropping the table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named dbo.ReferenceDetails which contains several millions of records.  Here is the create and select script of my table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RefDetails](
      [REQ_XREF_TYPE] [varchar](12) NULL
    , [REQUEST_ID] [varchar](24) NULL
    , [CROSS_REFERENCE] [varchar](32) NULL
    , [RUN_BY] [varchar](100) NULL
    , [RUN_DATE] [datetime] NULL
    , [ISCURRENTRECORD] [int] NULL
    , [RECORDSTARTDATE] [datetime2](7) NULL
    , [RECORDENDDATE] [datetime2](7) NULL
    , [UPDATE_FLAG] [varchar](50) NULL
    , [SECUREFLAG] [int] NULL
    , [EVENT_TIMESTAMP] [datetime2](7) NULL 
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

SELECT TOP (10) 
   [REQ_XREF_TYPE]
  ,[REQUEST_ID]
  ,[CROSS_REFERENCE]
  ,[RUN_BY]
  ,[RUN_DATE]
  ,[ISCURRENTRECORD]
  ,[RECORDSTARTDATE]
  ,[RECORDENDDATE]
  ,[UPDATE_FLAG]
  ,[SECUREFLAG]
  ,[EVENT_TIMESTAMP]
FROM [dbo].[ReferenceDetails]
```

Can I alter the table so that `REQ_XREF_TYPE`, `ISCURRENTRECORD` and `EVENT_TIMESTAMP` is Primary Key and `NOT NULL` without dropping the table?

Your response will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Any alterations to a large table may take time just be prepared for that.  Before you can make a column not null you have to make sure there are no null values in the table FIRST.  Then you can do an alter table script and just change it to NOT NULL for that column.

Comment: Sure: `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT`. Be aware that if the table currently has no PK at all, it probably has no clustered index either, and your new primary key would become the clustered index. That means the whole table will be rewritten as part of adding this constraint, which can be quite expensive (especially if you're not expecting it).

Comment: It would help more if you provided the CREATE TABLE DDL rather than select query. Yes, you can change a column to not allow null and create a primary key. The performance of doing so will depend on your existing structure and SQL Server edition. Add that to your question.

Comment: I upvoted @DanGuzman, and I want to add a +1 here; Please give us the DDL, also it would still help to provide a small sample of data. There are some other suggestions if the `alter` isn't straight forward.

Comment: Why do you ask?  Did you try something and get an error?  Why did your research lead you to ask this question?

Comment: Yes you can, if the combination of these 3 fields is unique and it will take some time to  complete your DDL command to

Comment: @Dan Guzman : Here is the create script.                                         
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RefDetails](
 [REQ_XREF_TYPE] [varchar](12) NULL,
 [REQUEST_ID] [varchar](24) NULL,
 [CROSS_REFERENCE] [varchar](32) NULL,
 [RUN_BY] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [RUN_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
 [ISCURRENTRECORD] [int] NULL,
 [RECORDSTARTDATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
 [RECORDENDDATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
 [UPDATE_FLAG] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [SECUREFLAG] [int] NULL,
 [EVENT_TIMESTAMP] [datetime2](7) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: @GuidoG The column IScURRENTRECORD is not unique. It contains only 1 and 0. But the other two columns are unique.

Comment: @AritraSarkar That is not what I mean. Each of these 3 columns does not have to be unique. Their combined values should be unique if you want to make the primary key from these 3 values

Comment: Thanks a lot @GuidoG. Now, the concept is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below. You first need to convert the columns to NOT NULL then you create the Primary Key. If you already have data in the table then the creation of the primary key may take some time.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RefDetails] ALTER COLUMN [REQ_XREF_TYPE] VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RefDetails] ALTER COLUMN [ISCURRENTRECORD] INT NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RefDetails] ALTER COLUMN [EVENT_TIMESTAMP] DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RefDetails] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_RefDetails PRIMARY KEY ([REQ_XREF_TYPE],[ISCURRENTRECORD],[EVENT_TIMESTAMP]);
```

Note: Your creation script says the table name is RefDetails but your OP says ReferenceDetails. I went with the creation script name.

**Update:**

The Primary Key requires that any column(s) selected contain a unique combination - duplicates are not allowed. If duplicates exist, the creation of the primary key will fail. To check for duplicates before creating a primary key, run the following:

```
SELECT [REQ_XREF_TYPE], [ISCURRENTRECORD], [EVENT_TIMESTAMP], CountDupes = COUNT(1)
FROM [dbo].[RefDetails]
GROUP BY [REQ_XREF_TYPE], [ISCURRENTRECORD], [EVENT_TIMESTAMP]
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY [REQ_XREF_TYPE], [ISCURRENTRECORD], [EVENT_TIMESTAMP]
```

You are expecting 0 results, which means there are no duplicates. Any result will identify the unique set of duplicate records along with the number of times they are duplicates (see the CountDupes column result).

If you get 0 results, then you are clear to create the primary key.

If you get any results, then you will need to address this (i.e., remove the duplicates or include additional columns that create a unique combination).

Comment: Thanks @J Weezy. I'm new to Sql server. I would like to let you know before hand that the column  ISCURRENTRECORD is not unique. It contains only 1 and 0. But the other two columns are unique. So, if I try to alter ISCURRENTRECORD to PK, along with with the other two columns, it would be fine right?

Comment: @AritraSarkar SQL Server will check to make sure that all three columns combine to create a unique record. Any duplicates found will result in a PRIMARY KEY VIOLATION. I will update my answer to all you to determine whether the composite contains duplicate records.

Comment: Thanks @ J Weezy. Now it is very clear. I will run the above scripts and lets see. Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried the alter script for a table which has a less amount of records. Here is what I tried. ALTER TABLE ELLIPSE.RefHeaderDetails ALTER COLUMN [ENTITY_TYPE] VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE ELLIPSE.RefHeaderDetails ALTER COLUMN [REF_NO] VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE ELLIPSE.RefHeaderDetails ALTER COLUMN [ISCURRENTRECORD] INT NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE ELLIPSE.RefHeaderDetails ALTER COLUMN [EVENT_TIMESTAMP] DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE ELLIPSE.RefHeaderDetails ADD CONSTRAINT PK_RefHeaderDetails PRIMARY KEY ([ENTITY_TYPE],[REF_NO],[ISCURRENTRECORD],[EVENT_TIMESTAMP])

Comment: It gives an error as follows :Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'RefHeaderDetails'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 5
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: @AritraSarkar That is because you are attempting to modify table RefHeaderDetails, instead of RefDetails.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I was using the above script for a different table named RefHeaderDetails, as this table contains less data. If the script works fine for this table then I will use this for RefDetails table.

Comment: @AritraSarkar I see. Try running the three NOT NULL scripts first. Then run the creation of the Primary Key script.

Comment: @AritraSarkar You're welcome. You might want to consider marking your question as answered.